# Join two select statements containing a where clause using alasql in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, alasql

I am using alasql in node.js, and I cannot get a join to work.

Here you have dummy data:

```
x = [ 
{ date: 20180501, price: 23, product: 'x' },
{ date: 20180501, price: 46, product: 'y' },
{ date: 20180502, price: 29, product: 'x' },
{ date: 20180502, price: 50, product: 'y' },
{ date: 20180503, price: 22, product: 'x' },
{ date: 20180503, price: 43, product: 'y' },
{ date: 20180504, price: 21, product: 'x' },
{ date: 20180504, price: 43, product: 'y' },
{ date: 20180505, price: 26, product: 'x' },
{ date: 20180505, price: 48, product: 'y' }]
```

I would like to get, for each day, the ratio between the price of product y and product y. So, my desired output is:

```
desiredOutput = [ 
{ date: 20180501, price_ratio: 46/23},  
{ date: 20180502, price_ratio: 50/29},  
{ date: 20180503, price_ratio: 43/22},
{ date: 20180504, price_ratio: 43/21},
{ date: 20180505, price_ratio: 48/26}]
```

I am attempting to get this with the following query:

```
alasql("select date, price_y/price_x as price_ratio from (select date, price as price_y from ? where product='y') as y join (select date, price as price_x from ? where product='x') as x on x.date=y.date", [x,x])
```

But I can't get it to work. It doesn't crash or anything, but I only get price_x, not the ratio. This is what I get:

```
[ 
{ date: 20180501, price_x: 23 },
{ date: 20180502, price_x: 29 },
{ date: 20180503, price_x: 22 },
{ date: 20180504, price_x: 21 },
{ date: 20180505, price_x: 26 } ]
```

I can get the desired result by running and storing each subquery separately, and then performing the join using those objects, but I would like to know how to do it with just nested subqueries, in a single call.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

<s>/* to get produt x and y prices for each date */
const res = alasql("select date, sum(case when product='x' then price else null end) as price_x, sum(case when product='y' then price else null end) as price_y from ? group by date", [x])</s>

```
/* to get ratio */
```

```js
    const res1 = alasql("select date, concat(price_y, '/', price_x) price_ratio from (select date, sum(case when product='x' then price else null end) as price_x, sum(case when product='y' then price else null end) as price_y from ? group by date)", [x])
    
    // console.log(res)
    console.log(res1)
```

EDIT: added [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/18pcgedp/)

Comment: Thanks :)
But this is not what I wanted. Is there any way to get the join statement to work properly?

Comment: Updated my answer, you asked for y/x but I gave you x/y, maybe that's the part that didn't satisfy your expectation?

Comment: Not really :)   The thing is, as I said in my question, I CAN obtain the desired results by means of an intermediate object, but what I want to achieve is getting the join statement to work. I can't seem to get a join statement joining subqueries with where clauses to work.

Comment: `res1` is independent, you don't need `res` to get to res1 in my code, I wrote it that way so hopefully you understand how I get there.

Comment: Did you find a solution about the join statement? I'm getting the very same result as yours, and as you say the proposed solution uses 2 different queries while the requirement is to use one single query with the join statement.

Comment: @edoedoedo my solution DOESN'T need two statements. The first one is just to demonstrate how to put both price_x and price_y into the same row per date. The 2nd statement with the comment "to get ratio" is the one that should solve the OP's problem.

Comment: You know what, since you asked, let me just update my answer by crossing out the first one, as the second statement doesn't depend on the first one anyway.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand, so let me clarify: @DanielOrtega is trying to get some result composing nested subqueries in alasql, and is claiming that the result metadata is unexpected; you are correctly saying that that result can be simply be obtained with a direct query without subqueries, and in fact your sample query returns the correct result. However, even if the OP's query is unnecessary complex, the result from alasql is still unexpected! Found out that there is a bug with joins and nested queries, see https://github.com/AlaSQL/alasql/issues/1789